# How to trigger the onClick event of a marker on a Google Maps V2 for Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

Is there a way of calling onClick event of a specific marker manually (without physically tapping the marker)?

Comment: What about `mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(...);` ?

Comment: Rami how can that listener be called programmatically (without actually clicking the marker)

Answer (score 12):

No, **but you can simulate the onClick event**. 2 things happen when you click a marker:

1. The info window for the corresponding clicked marker is shown.
2. The camera pans to the marker.

The above can be achieved with 2 lines of code:

```
marker.showInfoWindow();
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(marker.getPosition()), 250, null);
```

Comment: Your forgot the directions icon appearing. Your solution will not work for that.

Comment: What's the solution for that? For triggering the directions icon?

Answer (score 4):

Try this ,

Implement marker click listener from your map class ,

```
public class MapView extends FragmentActivity implements OnMarkerClickListener{}
```

it will override onMarkerClickEvent as follows ,

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

**NO**, you can't triger a marker click event directly (from code).

You can just use `mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(...);`, to handle markers click event.

---

But there is an alternative if you use your map in [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html), so you can trigger a marker click event with `JavaScript`:

```
//In V2 version:
GEvent.trigger(markers[i], 'click');

//In V3 version:
google.maps.event.trigger(markers[i], 'click');
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. You can't set the `onClick` of a particular marker separately.

However , using `Map.setOnMarkerClickListener(_)` you can set a listener for all such events. You should be able to retrieve the `marker` object in the listener called whenever any marker is clicked . You can use some identification to see if this is the particular marker you desire and act accordingly.
The identification could be any of the properties specific to that marker , `title` being the obvious choice. However, you can filter markers using any desired property.

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled across this and wasn't helped by the answers. So for future readers - if you are adding a `map.setOnMarkerClickListener(yourClickHandler)`, then it's quite straight forward.

Abstract the logic from `yourClickHandler` and keep a reference to all the markers... I.e.

```
private val markers = arrayListOf<Marker>()
```

Wherever you add your markers to the map, also add them to your `markers` array. I.e. something like

```
val marker = MarkerOptions().position(...).......
markers.add(map.addMarker(marker))
```

And `yourClickHandler` would look something like

```
val yourClickHandler = GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {
    markerClickHandler(marker = it)
    return@OnMarkerClickListener false
}
```

Now, whenever you press a marker on the map, `yourClickHandler` will call `markerClickHandler()` and whatever you do in there will happen. Also, when you wan't to press a marker programmatically, simply pass that marker to `markerClickHandler`.

Comment: I was looking for this line markers.add(map.addMarker(marker)) thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

You CAN simulate a marker click. Create your MyMarkerManager class extending from MarkerManager class.

The class has a function onMarkerClick() which you can call manually to simulate the event.

For more details refer this link.
https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/MarkerManager.java

Answer (score 0):

The `GoogleMap` object has a method `Marker addMarker(mk: MarkerOptions)` that returns a proper `Marker` instead of `MarkerOptions`.

So as soon as you add it you can simulate click behavior as follows:

```kotlin
fun addAndZoom(mk: MarkerOptions, needsHighlight: Boolean) {
    mapView.getMapAsync { map ->
        val actualMarker = map.addMarker(mk)
        if(needsHighlight) {
            val cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mk.position, 14F)
            map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate)
            actualMarker.showInfoWindow()
        }
    }
}
```